ActiveMQ Artemis JAAS LDAP - logged-in user has no access to anything
I'm trying to add LDAP sign in feature to ActiveMQ Artemis instance
I've set my login.config like this:
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule sufficient
    debug=true
    initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
    connectionURL="ldap://office.company.com:389"
    connectionUsername="cn=ldap.user,ou=technical,ou=city,dc=office,dc=company,dc=com"
    connectionPassword="password"
    connectionProtocol=s
    connectionTimeout="5000"
    authentication=simple
    userBase="ou=department,ou=city,dc=office,dc=company,dc=com"
    userSearchMatching="(sAMAccountName={0})"
    userSearchSubtree=true
    readTimeout="5000"
    roleBase="ou=department,ou=city,dc=office,dc=company,dc=com"
    roleName="cn"
    roleSearchMatching="(&(objectClass=group)(cn=R&D-Dev)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn={0}))"
    roleSearchSubtree=true;

    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule optional
    reload=true
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};

Then I changed default value in artemis.profile from HAWTIO_ROLE='amq' to HAWTIO_ROLE='\*'.
This configuration allows me to log in with the LDAP account but wherever I check I'm receiving an error like this:
 ERROR: User not authorized to access attribute: AddressLimitPercent (class java.lang.SecurityException)

My LDAP tree looks like this
dc=com
└── dc=company
    └── dc=office
        ├── ou=city
        │   ├── ou=technical
        │   │   └── cn=ldap.user
        │   └── ou=department
        │       ├── sAMAccountName=name.lastname
        │       └── cn=R&D-Dev

I've tried mapping my LDAP role to internal amq role in artemis-roles.properties:
amq = R&D-Dev


My management.xml file looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--
    ~ Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    ~ contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
    ~ this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    ~ The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    ~ (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    ~ the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
    ~
    ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    ~
    ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    ~ limitations under the License.
    -->
<management-context xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
    <!--<connector connector-port="1099"/>-->
    <authorisation>
        <allowlist>
        <entry domain="hawtio"/>
        </allowlist>
        <default-access>
        <!--
        The "default-access" settings apply to every MBean not explicitly configured
        in the "allowlist" or "role-access" sections
        -->

        <!-- allow read-only access by default -->
        <access method="list*" roles="*"/>
        <access method="get*" roles="*"/>
        <access method="is*" roles="*"/>
        <access method="set*" roles="*"/>
        <access method="*" roles="*"/>
        <access method="browse*" roles="*"/>
        <access method="count*" roles="*"/>

        <!-- don't allow write or other operations by default -->
        <!--access method="set*" roles="amq"/-->
        <!--access method="*" roles="amq"/-->
        </default-access>
        <role-access>
        <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
            <access method="list*" roles="*"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="*"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="*"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="*"/>
            <!-- Note count and browse are need to access the browse tab in the console -->
            <access method="browse*" roles="*"/>
            <access method="count*" roles="*"/>
            <access method="*" roles="*"/>
        </match>
        <!--example of how to configure a specific object -->
        <!--
        <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis" key="subcomponent=queues">
            <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="update,amq"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
        </match>
        -->
        </role-access>
    </authorisation>
</management-context>

I also checked connection to REST API with this command
curl -k -H "Origin: https://activemq.dev.company.com" -u test:password https://activemq.dev.company.com/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\"/Active

Result for default account:
{"request":{"mbean":"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\"","attribute":"Active","type":"read"},"value":true,"timestamp":1724063227,"status":200}

Result for LDAP account:
{"request":{"mbean":"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\"","attribute":"Active","type":"read"},"error_type":"java.lang.Exception","error":"java.lang.Exception : User not authorized to access attribute: Active","status":403}

I also tried to map my LDAP role to internal amp role in broker.xml but it does not seem to work at all:
          <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="browse" roles="*"/>
                <permission type="send" roles="*"/>
                <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
                <permission type="manage" roles="*"/>
            </security-setting>
            <role-mapping from="cn=R&amp;D-Dev,ou=department,ou=city,dc=office,dc=company,dc=com" to="amq"/>
          </security-settings>

Performed double check then enabled DEBUG mode via 'log4j2.properties'. It turned out that user is receiving his role from LDAP service as expected
2024-08-19 09:42:48,432 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule] Roles [R&D-Dev] for user name.lastname

How may I grant access to my LDAP user?

Can you paste your management.xml?

Hi @JustinBertram there you go

I realised that in management.xml roles provided in <access method/> are supposed to be provided WIHTOUT space and escaped for xml format.
Such example resolved my issue
        <access method="list*" roles="amq,r&amp;d-dev"/>

